# how to create breadcrumbs in Grails application

Tags: grails

can any one please suggest me how breadcrumbs can be implemented in Grails 2.3.1.
Need to implemented to show navigation from home page to current page

For Example,

Home > Page 1 > Current Page

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [plugin here](https://grails.org/plugin/groovy-breadcrumbs-plugin) . The detailed [documentation](https://github.com/cyrilkiller/groovy-breadcrumbs-plugin) shows the usage

Installation:

grails install-plugin groovy-breadcrumbs-plugin

Using:

The breadcrumbs plugin is based on a MenuDefinitionService is provided by the application. So let's go create the service

Run create-service MenuDefinitionService

In MenuDefinitionService create a method called loadMenuDefinition

example

```
class MenuDefinitionService  {

    static transactional = false

    static scope = "session"

    static proxy = true


    def loadMenuDefinition() {
        def menus = []

        menus << new MenuItem(name : "page-one", message:"page.one.demo", controller: "BreadCrumbsDemo", action: "pageOne")
        MenuItem menuThreeTwo = new MenuItem(name : "page-two-", message:"page.two.demo", controller: "BreadCrumbsDemo", action:"pageThreeTwo")
        menuThreeTwo << new MenuItem(name : "page-two.one", message:"page.two.one.demo", controller: "BreadCrumbsDemo", action:"pageThreeTwoOne")
        menuThreeTwo << new MenuItem(name : "page-two.two", message:"pagetwo.two.demo", controller: "BreadCrumbsDemo", action:"pageThreeTwoTwo")
        menus << menuThreeTwo

        menus
    }
}
```

You can define as many levels that you want !!!